# How to get my website (fast) indexed after change from noindex to index?

Tags: nofollow, noindex

I have accidentally put index.html with "noindex,nofollow" to my webserver and left it for few days. 
Now I have changed it to "index,follow", added sitemap.xml, and added webpage to google webmaster.

What can I do more to tell google to index it ASAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the Google Webmaster Tools "Fetch as Google" option in the Crawl section. After you fetch a page, you have the option to submit it to the index, you can also tell them to crawl all the links on the page submitted (choose "Crawl this URL and its direct links" after clicking on "Submit to index"). i think Google Webmaster Tools limits users to 10 submissions per day.

The Analytics will not help getting the pages re-indexed.

To check how many pages are indexed, use the "site:" query (type in Google -  [site:mydomain.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=api%20for%20website%20traffic&gl=US&gws_rd=ssl#gl=US&q=site%3adomain.com)).

What may help speed things up is getting the pages a few links from external sites, this can even be done by using ping services, or RSS submissions. Just don't spam or get low quality links, or you may get banned from Google.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing more you can do. But think about it, *everyone* wants their site indexed as soon as possible. If there was a way to do it, everyone would do it, and it would quickly become as slow as just waiting...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to get a website with `noindex` in the past in the Google search engine.

Options to get organized:

- Provide links from other websites to your website
- Implement Google Analytics
- Register within the Google Webmaster Tools, the location of the `sitemap.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Google Webmaster Tools allows you to submit your website for indexing. There is no guarantee that they will do so, but it's worth doing anyway (that's why the service exists).

You can submit your URL for indexing here:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url/

And here is some more information:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1352276?hl=en